# Android BackGround Service With HTTPS and Location Request

Tags: android, performance

Does 436 HTTPS request and 36 location request per day on background of an android app drain battery high?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion 436 HTTPS requests would not cause severe battery drain but location might do but
Thats depends on how you are requesting location from location manager.

Are you requesting location updates after regular interval? 
e.g. `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE, locationListener);`

If yes then that requires location services always ON and that may cause battery drain.

Comment: I am taking location everyday from 9 am to 6 pm in background using IntentService and AlarmManager for every 15 minutes interval.

Comment: Oh That means 9 hrs a day your location services are on... then unfortunately yes it will significantly drain battery. You can observe battery consumption with location services ON and  battery consumption with location services OFF. That will give you better idea

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS requests doesn't have any effect on the battery but location listening might cause a battery drain if you used it wrong.
For example requesting a location update and never removing it will cause the location listener to always search for location in background and it depends on which provider you use either GPS or NETWORK, so my advice to u is to set and scheduled requests and every time you request an location update once you get the location remove the location update request so it do not keep getting the location

Comment: Which cause battery drain enable location throughout the day or update location every 10 min only for 9 hours?